# Problem in WHERE Clause of null value in RavenDb

Tags: null, ravendb

I have the following statement (using RavenDb):

```
session.Query<Container>().Where(c=>c.ParentId == null).Count();
```

When I run the above, the count is always 0, but if I do this instead:

```
session.Query<Container>().ToList().Where(c=>c.ParentId == null).Count();
```

It returns the correct number.

Anyone have the clue on how to achieve this? Is RavenDb got a different handling of null value in it's query?

-- UPDATE --

I tested the above statements in localhost:8080 rather than before (which is in IIS deployment, on remote host) and it works. Maybe it is my IIS configuration problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right RavenDB handles null differently (because it uses Lucene under the hood).

I'd recommend posting this on the mailing list, so that it can be fixed. See http://groups.google.com/group/ravendb.

Comment: Yeah, I do posted there. Should I just use Lucene to work around on the above matter?